# How to determine if a jobject is a LocalRef or GlobalRef?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

When working with the `JNI` I'm trying to figure out, if given an arbitrary `jobject`, is it possible to determine if it's a `LocalRef` or `GlobalRef`?

Unfortunately both `NewLocalRef` and `NewGlobalRef` return the same `jobject` type even though both need to be released differently.

If this isn't possible, can one at least assume that all `jobject`s either passed as argument into native functions called directly from Java, or returned from JNI calls (other that `NewGlobalRef`) are all `LocalRef`s.

I can't find any documentation to confirm that assumption is valid, though it certainly seems to be on Oracle Java and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can one at least assume that all jobjects either passed as argument into native functions called directly from Java

These are always LocalRefs.

> or returned from JNI calls (other that NewGlobalRef) are all LocalRefs.

What a method returns is up to it. You can't make any assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for that EJP, just a quick clarification on the second question - I'm mainly worried about the functions like `CallObjectMethod` or `NewObject` which return a reference to a Java side object. Would you happen to know if it's safe to assume they're `LocalRefs`?

Comment: Any JNI method will return a `LocalRef` rather than a `GlobalRef`, except of course `NewGlobalRef()`. It's stated in the JNI Specification somewhere.